# query all audit entries defined with 'audit' command

Tags: oracle, audit

what is the command to list all audit entries defined with `audit` command? Is there any command for it or maybe tableName to query from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the method you use for auditing, you can find that information in the below views:

- DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS
- DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS
- DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS
- AUDIT_UNIFIED_POLICIES
- AUDIT_UNIFIED_ENABLED_POLICIES

The content of the audit trail, also depending on configuration and version, can be found in the below views:

- DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL
- UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL